# Adding two functions together in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Hi I am new in Haskell and I came across an interesting problem but I was not really sure on how I would go about solving it. I am about to show you only two parts of the question as an example.

The question is that we are to input a number between 13 to 15 digits.
then from that number we remove the last number. such as 19283828382133 should out put the exact same number just without the final 3, 1928382838213.

Then every odd digit(not number) from these numbers will be doubled. So you will get 2,9,4,8,6 etc

This is my code so far. As you can see from the code I have been able to complete these two parts individually(working) but I am not sure how **I would add them together.**

```
lastdigit :: Integer -> Integer -- This Function removes the last number
lastdigit x = x`div`10

doubleOdd (x:xs) = (2*x):(doubleEven xs) -- This function doubles every odd digit not number.
doubleOdd [] = []
doubleEven (x:xs) = x:(doubleOdd xs)
doubleEven [] = []
```

So to further explain the program I am trying to build will first go through the step of taking in the number between 13 to 15 digits. Then it will first remove the last number then automatically go to the  next step of doubling each odd digit(not number). Thanks

Comment: But if the odd digits are greater than or equal to 5, then what happens? Since then than the "new" digit is larger than 10.

Comment: That is actually the next part of the problem. In which if you got 10 it would just become a 1  because 10  is 1 + 0  which = 1. if you got something like 14 it would become a 5 because 1 + 4 = 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing component is a way to break down an integer into its digits, and build it back up from there. That's easy:

```
digits:: Int -> [Int]
digits = map (`mod` 10) . takeWhile (/= 0) . iterate (`div` 10)

undigits :: [Int] -> Int
undigits = foldr f 0 where f i r = 10 * r + i
```

Then it looks like you need to post-process those digits in two different ways, but only if they match a predicate. Let's build a combinator for that:

```
when :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
when p f a = if p a then f a else a
```

The first case appears when you want to double digits in odd position (from left to right). Again trivial, with the minor inconvenience that `digits` breaks down a number by increasing power of ten. Let's prefix each number by its position:

```
prefix :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
prefix is = let n = length is in zip [n, n-1..1] is
```

`doubleOdd` can now be expressed as

```
doubleodd :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleodd = map (snd . when (odd . fst) (id *** double)) . prefix
```

You mentioned in a comment that when the double number overflows, its digits must be added together. This is the second case I was referring to and is again simplicity itself:

```
double :: Int -> Int
double = when (>= 10) (sum . digits) . (* 2)
```

Here is your final program:

```
program = undigits . doubleodd . tail . digits
```

... assuming the "between 13 and 15 digits" part is verified separately.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need a way to break some large number into digits.

```
digits :: Integral x => x -> [x]
digits 0 = []
digits x = digits (x `div` 10) ++ [x `mod` 10]
```

Which gives you...

```
Prelude> digits 12345
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

You can then drop the last digit with `init`

```
Prelude> (init . digits) 12345
[1,2,3,4]
```

The a helper function to `map` over odd elements in a list.

```
mapOdd _ [] = []
mapOdd f (x:[]) = [f x]
mapOdd f (x:y:rest) = f x : y : mapOdd f rest
```

Giving you...

```
Prelude> mapOdd (+10) [1..10]
[11,2,13,4,15,6,17,8,19,10]
```

And a function to get back to a large number...

```
undigits = sum . zipWith (*) [10^n | n <- [0..]] . reverse
```

Resulting in...

```
Prelude> undigits [1, 2, 3, 4]
1234
```

And putting it all together

```
Prelude> undigits . mapOdd (*2) . init . digits $ 12345
2264
```

---

In functional languages particularly, always try to solve a problem by composing solutions to smaller problems :)

Comment: Alot of the code you have written has been directly written in the prelude I was looking for an approach more looking towards loading a single text.hs file including the code and then just loading and running it. Thanks

Comment: In the final solution `sumDigits . mapOdd (*2) . init . digits` 3/4 functions are not defined in the `Prelude`. I assume you mean that the answer was presented in the context of a ghci session, rather than a complete module. If you want a module, everything you need is there.

Comment: Shouldn't `digits 0` give `[0]`?

Comment: @Elmex80s I thought it reasonable to ignore this case given the problem, for simplicity. But you're right. To get around this you'd either need to define a wrapper function to handle that case, or fallback to hacky string splitting solutions :)

Comment: @JordanMackie if you were looking at handling those edge cases, probably best to implement digits as consing each digit, then reversing the result in the wrapper function (`digits' 0 = []; digits' x = let (d, m) = x `divMod` 10 in m : digits d` and `digits 0 = ['0']; digits x = reverse . digits' $ x`)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps and realize it could be cleaned up a lot. List indices start with 0 which is also an even number and the first element of a list. The list comprehension processes 0,2,4 ... the 1st,2nd and 3rd items.

```
let f n = [mod n 10] ++ f (div n 10)
let r = [if even i then d*2 else d|(i,d)<-zip [0..] (init.reverse.take 14.f$19283828382133)]
sum [b*(10^a)|(a,b) <- zip [12,11..0] r]
```

2948684868416

If you want it to handle any length number, the easiest way here is `length $ show 19283828382133` but I do have a function somewhere that does that. Use the length as a value in 3 places, once at full value in the`take` function in the composition.